# Babel does not accept options

Tags: webpack, babeljs

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'test.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env', {
                            targets: {
                                chrome: 52
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Looks simple, yet it throws error

> Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /src/app.js: Unknown option: foreign.targets. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

that doesn't make any sense. Error is triggered by options for "env" preset. Any ideas why babel preset suddenly doesn't accept options?

Answer (score 9):

Figured it out. Preset with options should be in nested array, so correct options list should be like this:

```
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        ['env', {
                            targets: {
                                chrome: 52
                            }
                        }]
                    ]
                }
```